# the sub x86-instruction question

Tags: x86

Assume that we have the following c code

```
void fun(void){
    printf("this is fun\n");
}
```

Then, we compile it with debug mode, we get the following disassemble code:

```
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
sub esp, 0xc0
...
```

Ok,we just discuss:

```
sub esp, 0xc0
```

My question is: why is the default value here `0xc0`, not the other value, such as `0xF0`, `0xFF`… and so on?

Comment: There is nothing here that is actually specific to Unix and Linux.

Comment: Where do you get `0xf0` from?

Comment: Assuming that disassembly uses Intel syntax and I understood it correctly, the disassembly stores the previous value of the EBP register to the stack, copies the stack pointer to EBP, and then decrements the stack pointer by 0xc0, effectively allocating 192 bytes of stack space as some temporary storage area. Why 192? Probably because the routine that follows will only need exactly that much at maximum!

Comment: @telcoM yes, it’s a standard stack frame setup, but the 0xC0 value isn’t easy to explain (I get 8 with my GCC). Stack guards perhaps (red zones etc.)? The difficult part is guessing what “compile it with debug mode” means in terms of an actual compiler command.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Only x86-64 System V has a red-zone, out of any standard x86 calling convention.  Unless this is x32 (32-bit pointers in long mode), code using `esp` doesn't have a red zone.  Besides that, a red zone means you *don't* have to `sub rsp, anything` to reserve space in a leaf function, because you can simply use space below the stack pointer and be guaranteed that it won't be asynchronously clobbered.  I wondered if `0xc0` is a typo for `0x0c`, but that wouldn't make sense after `push ebp`.  We only need 8 more bytes to re-align the stack by 16 before a `call`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard stack frame setup, saving the stack pointer then using EBP for indexing. The amount subtracted from ESP is what is allocated for the procedure's local variable storage, and local variables will be accessed by referencing [EBP-??].

Without seeing the code for your procedure it is difficult to say why it allocates that much storage. There is no default value used by the compiler, it always allocates exactly what is needed. It can do this because local variables types must be explicitly declared, and the compiler knows how much space is used by each type. There is no randomness or uncertainty in it, and no benefit to allocating extra storage. I also can't see how randomizing the local variable storage size would prevent any kind of stack-based attack. Most modern processors have hardware data execution prevention measures in place, making these attacks impossible anyway.